# Getting image from DOCKER API using blob

Tags: docker

I'm trying to download a image using POSTMAN, so I'm trying to execute the following steps:

1- Get the manifest information:

```
GET https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/ubuntu/manifests/latest
```

So I get the following response:

```
   {
   "schemaVersion": 1,
   "name": "library/ubuntu",
   "tag": "latest",
   "architecture": "amd64",
   "fsLayers": [
      {
         "blobSum": "sha256:a3ed95caeb02ffe68cdd9fd84406680ae93d633cb16422d00e8a7c22955b46d4"
      },
      {
         "blobSum": "sha256:7fc152dfb3a6b5c9a436b49ff6cd72ed7eb5f1fd349128b50ee04c3c5c2355fb"
      },
      {
         "blobSum": "sha256:ee671aafb583e2321880e275c94d49a49185006730e871435cd851f42d2a775d"
      },
      {
         "blobSum": "sha256:d83811f270d56d34a208f721f3dbf1b9242d1900ad8981fc7071339681998a31"
      },
      {
         "blobSum": "sha256:5667fdb72017d1fb364744ca1abf7b6f3bbe9c98c3786f294a461c2866db69ab"
      }
   ],
   "history": [
      {
         "v1Compatibility": ""
      },
      {
         "v1Compatibility": "{\"id\":\"4b728884276a5a8a34fbbb300b46b18c6b9382cdeb8a85d0520c8d34068e5fb0\",\"parent\":\"66c93443725d82003c60a47d21f5484432b5ec76c8bfadd32c8a41edba1f8060\",\"created\":\"2019-09-18T23:20:27.334214267Z\",\"container_config\":{\"Cmd\":[\"/bin/sh -c mkdir -p /run/systemd \\u0026\\u0026 echo 'docker' \\u003e /run/systemd/container\"]}}"
      },
      {
         "v1Compatibility": ""
      },
      {
         "v1Compatibility": "{\"id\":\"86feef564c750ab53d7473a1507b6b1109fd2cbc7bfdb244bc5645eec1f3675f\",\"parent\":\"53e1edbd56e089206a1ef26dacddf818d2926905e4981d7d98d2a9b017aca0a8\",\"created\":\"2019-09-18T23:20:25.907034433Z\",\"container_config\":{\"Cmd\":[\"/bin/sh -c [ -z \\\"$(apt-get indextargets)\\\" ]\"]}}"
      },
      {
         "v1Compatibility": "{\"id\":\"53e1edbd56e089206a1ef26dacddf818d2926905e4981d7d98d2a9b017aca0a8\",\"created\":\"2019-09-18T23:20:25.001198355Z\",\"container_config\":{\"Cmd\":[\"/bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:288ac0434f65264f3c50cf3e2766c5dbf3fa953c89995dd9445063fd565aac81 in / \"]}}"
      }
   ],
   "signatures": [
      {
         "header": {
            "jwk": {
               "crv": "P-256",
               "kid": "G3BK:3LIN:YT77:4BNT:KEVY:VX5N:YQEA:ECEW:UBBI:OOB6:7C3W:WACE",
               "kty": "EC",
               "x": "-VsbPz10h4THvkv3wusAf_AgXf5unH39JU47JaT1A80",
               "y": "baBL61yOF1J5hDslfyyiPRrx0GoyU-UqYo10-sekyJM"
            },
            "alg": "ES256"
         },
         "signature": "d0kjLJ9Gt_o0vm8xe0WK9b2bHL_bJHAP4yo-kKuZLQce4ztHPuoE6rvrxdTkIF6qId_bZARJZ6tLY3tiHa3aRQ",
         "protected": "eyJmb3JtYXRMZW5ndGgiOjQ5MzMsImZvcm1hdFRhaWwiOiJDbjAiLCJ0aW1lIjoiMjAxOS0wOS0yNlQyMDo1NDo1MFoifQ"
      }
   ]
}
```

2- Trying to download:

```
GET https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/ubuntu/blobs/{what I should put here}
```

Which blob I should put in URL? If I put the first blobSum inside fsLayer I can download the image but:

> docker: Error response from daemon: No command specified.

Comment: Your question appears mangled. According to Docker's spec, you should be able to provide the values of `blobSum` (digests) to get each layer: https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/#blob

Comment: Ok, but I didn't understand how join this blob values to get a complete image.

Comment: This  may help: https://medium.com/@jessgreb01/digging-into-docker-layers-c22f948ed612

Comment: Where does this error come from `docker: Error response from daemon: No command specified.`? You're pulling layers, not an image, when you do it from the API. You would need to package those layers and the manifest back into a format that docker understands if you want to import it back into docker.